# MYSQL Query Speed (Search vs Query)

Tags: mysql, search

I don't have my server up and running yet, so unfortunately I can't test yet, but I was hoping you could shed some light on a question I have.

So, Table A has an inverse one-to-many relationship with Table B, so would it be better to store the ID's of Table B in Table A search by ID, or would it be better/faster to query Table B for all results where it's Table A ID is equal to my Table A's ID?

Basically Search (Search for row based on ID) vs Query (Grab all rows that have a certain value).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  Could you give an example of the two table structures?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but thankfully Hampus was able to somehow understand it and answer. I guess an example would be a youTube video and its comments. Table A would store the Video and it's details and Table B would store the comments and their details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the column containing the ID in B is a (foreign) key. It is most certainly faster. Storing a non-scalars (ie. lists) in columns in a database is generally a bad idea.